# How to show a progress-bar on a

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, slideshow, android-progressbar

I am developing an application that has a home page with a progress bar I have to represent many progress bar on slideshow, I tried ViewFlipper but its only for images. What shall I do. help.`

```
 viewFlipper=findViewById(R.id.Vi);
    b = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
   viewFlipper.addView(b); //this doesn't work
```

the layout

```
 <ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/Vi"
    android:layout_width="412dp"
    android:layout_height="263dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.110000014"></ViewFlipper>
```

This where should the slideshow should be

[image]

Comment: use a layout, in which put the progressbar above your required view, and change it's visibility once you need to show/hide it.

Comment: thank you so much . but i did not understand "put the progressbar above your required view"

Answer (score 0):

Create a scroll view and add the progress bar on a recycler view as item in order to show them on the scroll view on parent app

Comment: you're welcome , so can you accept the answer please ?